# Using buttons to loop to the next element from the data fetched from database

Tags: php, css, sql, html

I want to have a next button on my Productdetails.php page that would show the next image fetched from the database using while loop. Below is the  productdetails.php  page shows details of a particular product.
I am using simple php format, How can I go about it? I have come this far at this point.

```
        <div class = "uniqueproduct"> 
        <?php 
            if (isset($_GET['id']))
            {
                $id = $_GET['id'];
                $query1 = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from products where PRODUCT_ID = $id");
                while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($query1)) {
        ?>

            <div class = "singleproduct">
            <?php echo '<img src = "data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($row1['PRODUCT_IMAGE']).'" alt = "" width = "250px" height ="300px"/>'; ?>
            </div>

            <div class = "productName">
            <?php echo $row1['PRODUCT_NAME']; ?>
            </div>

            <div class = "productDescription">
            <?php echo $row1['PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION'];?>
            </div>

            <div class = "productPrice">
            <?php echo $row1['PRODUCT_PRICE']; ?>
            </div>


            <?php
            }
            }
            ?>


        <button class = "btnPicture"> ..............</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Before you do that, ensure that `$_GET['id']`is actually an `int` or whatever the expected data format is meant to be. Make use of prepared statements to prevent SQL injection. Also, do a check of `num_rows` to ensure that the row actually exists to prevent errors.

Comment: As for your question: `<a href="my_page.php?id=$id + 1">Next</a>` with all from the above comment in place, that should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for that @Script47. I will take that into consderation

Comment: However, I've got this error when clicking the link-

Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\30304546\2017-09-11 Ginnieandpinney site\Productdetails.php on line 52.

The code line 52 is : while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($query1)) .

I can't follow what's happening.

Comment: Did you implement the changes mentioned in my first comment?

Comment: i haven't made changes for the sql injection yet but I did add the num_rows check. I think its the syntax error.